# In 1395, why was "her" used instead of "their"?

Tags: pronouns, middle-english, paleography

Why was "her" used here?

Wycliffe Bible
Mk.1:20

In accordance with [studylight.org](https://www.studylight.org/desk/index.cgi?sr=0&old_q=MArk%201&search_form_type=general&q1=Mark%201%3A19&s=2&t1=en_wyc&ns=0):

"...brother, in a boot makynge nettis. 20 And anoon he clepide hem; and **thei** leften Zebedee, **her** fadir, in the boot with hiryd seruauntis, and thei suweden hym. And thei entriden"

I think, that "their" should be used instead.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Middle English, ["her" means "their"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Middle_English_personal_pronouns_(table)). The Modern English "their" actually comes from Old Norse, while the equivalent (and predecessor) of Modern English "her" is "hire".

Comment: Does that mean that ModE 'their' came from northern dialects of ME which had 'their' in preconquest 1066 Danelaw areas? Or was it just a matter of orthography, simply that it was spelled 'her' but pronounced with a  dental fricative 'th'?

Comment: @Mitch It was definitely not just a matter of orthography. It was probably more complex than just northern vs southern dialects, but the th-initial forms borrowed from Norse were the ones that eventually won out, and they were more prevalent in the North, so roughly speaking, I’d say yes.

Answer (score 5):

You are right, for modern English.

In Wycliffe's time, the oblique cases of "they" were "her" or "hir", and "hem". "Their" and "them" were not widespread, though I think they were used in some dialects.

Comment: Did "they" also have a form without "t" letter?

Comment: oh, eyeballfrog has already answered my question.